# How to access Capistrano method from an outer static class?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

Simple question; so my deploy.rb script in capistrano looks like this, where I can use the **capture** function easily:

```
namespace :mycompany do
    def some_function()
        mylog = capture("some_command")
    end

    desc <<-DESC
        some task description
    DESC
    task :some_task do
        mylog = capture("some_command")
    end
end
```

However, if I use the method in a class, like this:

```
namespace :mycompany do
    class SomeClass
        def self.some_static_method()
            mylog = capture("some_command")
        end
    end
end
```

It fails miserably:

```
/config/deploy.rb:120:in `some_static_method': undefined method `capture' for #<Class:0x000000026234f8>::SomeClass (NameError)
```

How to do it then? This method doesn't seem to be static :( it's inside here (capistrano sources):

```
module Capistrano
    class Configuration
        module Actions
            module Inspect

                # Executes the given command on the first server targetted by the
                # current task, collects it's stdout into a string, and returns the
                # string. The command is invoked via #invoke_command.
                def capture(command, options={})
                    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suggested to use **include** this way:

```
namespace :mycompany do
    class SomeClass
        include Capistrano::Configuration::Actions::Inspect

        def self.some_static_method()
            mylog = self.new.capture("some_command")
        end
    end
end
```

But that failed with an error inside capture:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/inspect.rb:34:in `capture': undefined local variable or method `sudo' for #<#<Class:0x00000001cbb8e8>::SomeClass:0x000000027034e0> (NameError)
```

So what I simply did is pass the instance as a parameter (hacky but it works).

```
namespace :mycompany do
    def some_function()
        SomeClass.some_static_method(self)
    end

    class SomeClass
        def self.some_static_method(capistrano)
            mylog = capistrano.capture("some_command")
        end
    end
end
```

FML